# Scheduled refresh dataset in Power Bi from Power Automate (Microsoft Flow)

Tags: powerbi, refresh, power-automate

I have a Power BI project where the data is stored in sql server through DirectQuery. I would like to schedule the update of the report and therefore of the data, through Microsoft Automate (Flow).

[Flow scheduling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xruVZ.png)

When I run the schedule, however, I get this error message "Invalid dataset. This API can only be called on a Model-based dataset power bi".

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Invalid dataset. This API can only be called on a Model-based dataset"
  }
}
```

[Immage Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srwxN.png)

Why?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish Direct Query report to PBI Service, there is no need in scheduled refresh, the service is able to query the data directly. Only import datasets require refresh when published to PBI service. That is the reason of the error - there is basically nothing to refresh.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the replies. I saw that on power BI service I can schedule the refresh. Is there a way to schedule the refresh less than 15 minutes in Direct Query?

Comment: @EnricoBlandini I assume what you see is "Scheduled cache refresh" option, right? This is not the same thing as scheduled data refresh, it is basically the refresh of tiles and not the data itself. The miniumum possible value for scheduled cache refresh is 15 min. However, if you do not use dashboards frequently you will not really need this cache refresh: you can checke here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#live-connections-and-directquery-to-on-premises-data-sources